# Finding X & Y based off of Index

Tags: math

Good day all

I am having a math issue, it may be due to the lack of sleep but I am totally drawing a blank.

I need to find the x and y coordinates based off of the index.

So I know the width of the grid, the height and the index. But I dont know the X and Y coordinates. i need build a formula to get that data.

For example. I know the index of 9. Through a formula i need to be able to get the number 4 for X and 2 for Y

[image]

```
int numOfRows = 4
int numOfCols = 5
int index = 13

int X = ?
int Y = ?


//perform math magic
x = 4
y = 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very simple:

```
public static void foo(int i) {
    int x = i % 5 + 1;
    int y = i / 5 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It gets much easier if you start counting with 0:

```
 | 0  1  2  3  4
----------------- 
0| 0  1  2  3  4
1| 5  6  7  8  9
2|10 11 12 13 14
3|...
4|
```

Let `a` be the number in the grid and `numberOfCols` the number of columns (5 in this example).

In that case, it's plain to see that

- the row number is `a / numberOfCols` (without remainder) and
- the column number is `a modulo numberOfCols`.

---

You can reduce your case to this case by adding 1 to the resulting row/col numbers.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't seem to be working. 

float numOfCols = (SheetSize.x / BlockSize.x);
float numOfRows = (SheetSize.y / BlockSize.y);
Debug.Log("X: " + Mathf.Floor((index-1)/numOfCols)+1);
Debug.Log("Y: " + ((index -1)%numOfRows)+1);

Any idea?